# Are KITTI depth maps showing distance from camera point or camera plane?

Tags: lidar, kitti, lidar-data

I was always using KITTI raw LiDaR scans data set as a ground truth for my depth studies
and thought that they are representing distance between some point and camera plane, i.e. z coordinate.

For example, pixel depth of 364th row of the image below

[image]

is shown here

[image]

I got more or less the same distance for all the points on the road (left spikes in the plot) and conclude that the distance is from camera plane. If not, there should be some curvature.
Is my understanding correct?

Comment: this is lidar raw data? cant be.  are you using the LDIAR projected down data into the image plane? the pesodu depth. if it isprojected, then you should see some cluster of image due to the ring of detection for lidar on the ground

Comment: Hi Yuan,

I am using projected raw LiDaR scans data set (2 GB). What do you mean by "you should see some cluster of image due to the ring of detection for lidar on the ground" ?